# RegularExpressionValidator VS Ajax 1.0.20229

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, reg-expressionvalidator

We have a website that runs `.NET Framework 2.0` with `Ajax version 10618`.

But as it is, that is an old version of the dll, so we planned on switching it to the "newest"  version of it for the `.NET Framework 2.0`, the `AjaxControlToolkit version 20229`.

On our tests, we detected a problem with the ASP control `RegularExpressionValidator`, which used to work fine with the old version.

Whenever the input to the target control doesn't match the validation, the control displays my 
text, which in this case is a red asterisc dispositioned, like, in the next row, and it displays the following in the control: `"-1.7976931348623157e+308"`.

Theres nothing wrong with the expression because as I said, it works fine with the older version of `Ajax`, and I couldn't find anything related to `RegularExpressionValidators` and `Ajax` versions.

PS: Both the validator and the control are inside an UpdatePanel.

PS 2: With the older version, it would put a 0 in the control and then show me the red asterisc right beside it when the expression wouldn't match.

**Edit:**

Here's the control, fully copied:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValidateFooOrder" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFooNum"                                                    
Text="*" ErrorMessage="Invalid Foo number" 
ValidationExpression="^\d{0,4}$" ValidationGroup="GenerateFooFile" />
```

And it also has a `NumericUpAndDownExtender` attached to it:

```
<ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericExtenderFooNum" 
runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFooNum"                                                    
TargetButtonDownID="FooBack" TargetButtonUpID="FooForward" />
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if you are still having issues: Can you post your designer code? It would be interesting to look it over and see if this is a change in how the regex is handled by the control or how the javacript is written.

Comment: @Patricker Ok, added the code. Sorry it took long.

Comment: I'm assuming that the issue is still happening since you updated your question, right?

Comment: @Patricker Yes it still happening. After taking into account what little things we'd have to fix by switching the Ajax Version, we ended up not updating it at all.

Comment: I removed the [ajax] and [regex] tags as this question doesn't really have anything to do with ajax or regex (it's specific to the implementation of a specific vendor's control)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 It's specific to a vendor's control. That's all about ajax and regex. Those are Ajax's Toolkit controls, and one of them uses a regex. I'd keep those two tags.

Comment: @FelipeFiali Yes, the control uses Ajax and Regex, but this question is not about how to use ajax or regex - it's about how to get a control working: "Theres nothing wrong with the expression". The OP doesn't even mention ajax (beyond the toolkit name).

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Oh and I wrote something wrong on the other comment. I meant that its _not_ specific to a vendor's control. I'll just add the ajaxtoolkit tag then.

Comment: Try adding <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler,
           System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: some times the handlers are configured to support specific version.You might wanna add and extended version of script handler to make ajax compatible to your visual studio version

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've got the same issue and here are my findings:

First is the source of `-1.7976931348623157E+308`. It is equal to the `Minimum` property of `AjaxControlToolkit.NumericUpDownBehavior` which is called in one of the [Sys.Application.init Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397532%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) handlers:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.NumericUpDownBehavior, {"Maximum":1.7976931348623157E+308,"Minimum":-1.7976931348623157E+308, /* other non relevant stuff */);
});
```

So, no magic here, just a minimum value of `Double`. `Minimum` is the new property comparing to version 10618.

Next, why it is showed as soon as page is displayed? This happens because inside `readValue` function which is defined in `AjaxControlToolkit.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype` a value `this._min`(which is equal to `Minimum` parameter from `$create`) is assigned to input if it is empty. `readValue` sources:

```
readValue : function() {
        /// <summary>
        /// Parse value of textbox and this._currentValue to be that value.
        /// this._currentValue = this._min if some there is an exception
        /// when attempting to parse.
        /// Parse int or string element of RefValues
        /// </summary>

        if (this._elementTextBox) {
            var v = this._elementTextBox.value;
// The _currentValue of NumericUpDown is calculated here 
            // if textbox empty this._currentValue = this._min
            if(!this._refValuesValue) {
                if(!v) {
                    this._currentValue = this._min;
                } else {
                    try {
                        this._currentValue = parseFloat(v);
                    } catch(ex) {
                        this._currentValue = this._min;
                    }
                }
                if(isNaN(this._currentValue)) {
                    this._currentValue = this._min;
                }
// And assigned here. In case of empty input we will get -1.7976931348623157E+308 if Minimum was not changed
                this.setCurrentToTextBox(this._currentValue);
                this._valuePrecision = this._computePrecision(this._currentValue);
            } else {
                if(!v) {
                    this._currentValue = 0;
                } else {
                    var find = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < this._refValuesValue.length; i++) {
                        if (v.toLowerCase() == this._refValuesValue[i].toLowerCase()) {
                            find = i;
                        }
                    }
                    this._currentValue = find;
                }
                this.setCurrentToTextBox(this._refValuesValue[this._currentValue]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Before `Minimum`, in version 10618, default value was `0`. So I think described issue could be solved by specifying `Minimum` value explicitly in extender declaration:

```
<ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericExtenderFooNum" runat="server" 
     Minimum="0"
     TargetControlID="txtFooNum"
     TargetButtonDownID="FooBack" TargetButtonUpID
```

---

Another thing that I have found is that `change` event dispatching works wrong in new versions of IE (to make it work a Compatibility View should be enabled but I think this is not an option for public web sites).

The issue is in `setCurrentToTextBox` function. `event` object is always `null` in handlers (validation handlers for example) if created using [document.createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent).  To fix this issue, condition should be swapped, so all events in IE will be created using [createEventObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
// Current implementation of version 20229
setCurrentToTextBox : function(value) {
            // full sources are not shown, only if matters here

            if (document.createEvent) {
                // event is created using createEvent
            } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
                // event is created using createEventObject 
            }
        }
    }

// Updated implementation
setCurrentToTextBox : function(value) {
            // full sources are not shown, only if matters here

            if (document.createEventObject) {
                // event is created using createEventObject 
            } else if(document.createEvent) {
                // event is created using createEvent
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the error message, implies the number being tested is outside the boundaries of the expression.  The only allowed numbers are between 0 and 9999.  No letters, punctuation, or other characters are allowed.  The other part of the expression asserts anchors around the number, either as beginning and end of a line or word.  The only other allowed value is NULL, which is probably where the update is being more strict and giving the error.  For example, how do you validate a number or digit "\d" that does not exist (zero characters)?

Comment: My assumption (are these allowed?) is that most newer versions of anything fix bugs.  Having a validation defined as a number, yet allowing that value to be NULL is a bug.  The correct regular expression to validate a 1 to 4 digit number is "^\d{1,4}$" not 0,4.

Comment: Is that -1 because I did not agree with something?  My answer was directed at the regular expression being wrong, which is wrong in any language, not just AJAX.  The -1 is not justified and is unwarranted.

Comment: Your answer was speculation and doesn't even address the question of why an AJAX upgrade would change a legacy ASP.NET control.